# Como ler um arquivo JSON que está dentro de um pacote?

Tags: java, json, xml, packages

Preciso der um arquivo no caso `*.JSON`. Entendo que existe uma biblioteca para isso no caso utilizo a `json-simple-1.1.1`. Como é necessário fazer a leitura do arquivo primeiro e depois trabalhar com ele.

## Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Guardo o arquivo `file.json` dentro de um pacote `com.app.json` e preciso acessar esse arquivo.

Qual seria o método mais eficiente para acessar esse arquivo dentro do pacote?

## Observação:

Isso deve valer para arquivos `.json`, `.txt`, `.xml` e outros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que o pacote onde estarão os arquivos será sempre o mesmo. Desta forma, basta utilizar o código abaixo:

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/app/json/file.json") );
Object o = JSONValue.parse(in);
```

Caso contrário, você pode escrever uma função que receba o nome do pacote e transforme para um caminho válido dentro do classpath.

Abraços

Comment: Obrigado.
Por que você está utilizando "Object o = JSONValue.parse(in);" é uma forma exemplo?

Estou utilizando a seguinte linha: JSONObject jsonObjeto = (JSONObject) parser.parse(in);

Comment: Exatamente Eduardo, é apenas um exemplo. Você pode utilizar `JSONObject` se preferir. Note também que não é mandatório utilizar a classe `JSONValue`, você pode usar `JSONParser` também.